# Coffeescript variable declaration placed on the wrong place

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

**Coffeescript is placing the var directive on the wrong place. I have tried placing braces on the functios but no success. Here is the coffeescript code:**

```
jQuery (->

  $(".item-scaffold-edit").live("click", (=>
    element = $(this)
    cont = element.data("cont")
    url = element.data("url")
    $.ajax(url,
      dataType: "html"
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        $("##{cont}").html(data)
        $("##{cont}").data("url", url))))

  $(".item-menu").live("click", (=>
    element = $(this)
    cont = element.data("cont")
    url = element.data("url")
    if url isnt $("##{cont}").data("url")
      $.ajax(url,
        dataType: "html"
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
          $("##{cont}").html(data)
          $("##{cont}").data("url", url)
          $("#navbar-left li").removeClass("active")
          element.parent().addClass("active"))))
)
```

**It generates this:**

```
(function () {
  jQuery((function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(".item-scaffold-edit").live("click", (function () {
      var cont, element, url;
      element = $(_this);
      cont = element.data("cont");
      url = element.data("url");
      return $.ajax(url, {
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          $("#" + cont).html(data);
          return $("#" + cont).data("url", url);
        }
      });
    }));
    return $(".item-menu").live("click", (function () {
      var cont, element, url;
      element = $(_this);
      cont = element.data("cont");
      url = element.data("url");
      if (url !== $("#" + cont).data("url")) {
        return $.ajax(url, {
          dataType: "html",
          success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#" + cont).html(data);
            $("#" + cont).data("url", url);
            $("#navbar-left li").removeClass("active");
            return element.parent().addClass("active");
          }
        });
      }
    }));
  }));
}).call(this);
```

**But it should generate this:**

```
(function () {
  jQuery((function () {    
    $(".item-scaffold-edit").live("click", (function () {
      var cont, element, url;
      var _this = this;
      element = $(_this);
      cont = element.data("cont");
      url = element.data("url");
      return $.ajax(url, {
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          $("#" + cont).html(data);
          return $("#" + cont).data("url", url);
        }
      });
    }));
    return $(".item-menu").live("click", (function () {
      var cont, element, url;
      var _this = this;
      element = $(_this);
      cont = element.data("cont");
      url = element.data("url");
      if (url !== $("#" + cont).data("url")) {
        return $.ajax(url, {
          dataType: "html",
          success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#" + cont).html(data);
            $("#" + cont).data("url", url);
            $("#navbar-left li").removeClass("active");
            return element.parent().addClass("active");
          }
        });
      }
    }));
  }));
}).call(this);
```

**Anyone knows what's wrong with my coffeescript code????**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your example, you currently have:

```
foo -> bar => element = $(this)
```

which generates:

```
foo(function() {
  var _this = this;
  return bar(function() {
    var element;
    return element = $(_this);
  });
});
```

but you would like it to generate:

```
foo(function() {
  return bar(function() {
    var _this = this;
    var element;
    return element = $(_this);
  });
});
```

That would be identical to this:

```
foo(function() {
  return bar(function() {
    var element;
    return element = $(this);
  });
});
```

which you can generate using:

```
foo -> bar -> element = $(this)
```

eg, change the `=>` into a `->`. The documentation for the "fat arrow" is [here](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow), which explains how it differs from the normal arrow.

Comment: @user1411274 You can then remove all those extra braces and trust the indentation :) (it hurts to see those closing `))))` hehe)

Comment: @epidemian Removed... hehehehe